# What phrase do you use instead of "Nice to meet you" when the two of you have already met but

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage, conversation

I'm not a native English speaker. I would like to know what phrase can be used instead of

> "Nice to meet you"

when the two of you have already met but this just happens to be the first time you know each other's names? Like, the random neighbor you always say 'hi' to until one day you decide to ask what their name is, and then you tell them yours and now it's time for pleasantries. "Nice to meet you" obviously sounds weird. Thank you.

Comment: If ***meet*** bothers you (but it's not *restricted* to "first-time" encounters), just switch to ***see*** or ***chat with***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well it's really not that it bothers me, but I recently used the phrase "nice to meet you" in a similar context and had one of the most awkward moments of my life after because of how that person reacted. Are you 100% sure that you can use 'meet' too, even though you see the person regularly?

Comment: Okay, since you have now exchanged formalities, you can say "Nice to meet you formally."

Comment: @user34244: Of course I'm sure - I'm a native speaker! You're quite right that in many contexts ***meet*** may imply ***...for the first time***, but Google Books has over 70,000 written instances of [*to meet you **again***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to+meet+you+again%22), for example. Plus it's completely normal to say things like *I never expected to meet you here!*, where the implication is ***unexpectedly** encounter*.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, **but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions**, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the following in the exact same situation:

"Its nice to finally put a name to a familiar face."

"Nice to finally meet you."

"Nice to officially meet you."

"Its nice to finally know    your name."

"I feel like I already know you; its nice to finally meet    you."

Answer (score 1):

In the situation you describe, I (an American English native speaker) would likely say something like "It's good to finally meet you" or maybe "It's good to actually meet you", probably with a chuckle.

Comment: This happens a lot with parents -- you may not know someone's name (or know them only as _Bobby's dad_) and then you finally get introduced...  I usually say something like "_...officially meet you_".

Answer (score 0):

You can say "It feels good to have **acquainted myself** with you", "It feels good to have had this **little chat** with you", "It feels good to have **interacted** with you" or simply, "It feels good that I have got to know you."